# Specify interface to use for ssh connection

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm a noob, thank's for talking like "-verbose" to me, and sorry for my not too bad english I hope (:

I will try to express my problem as clear as possible.

Case 1:
Ethernet cable connected to computer for world wide web. Wifi connection disabled.

Problem: None!

Case 2:
Ethernet cable connected to computer. Wifi connection enabled through smartphone access point(no internet). This is for ssh connection to "headless" raspberry zero (don't really matter I think).

Problem: I have to disconnect cable for getting ssh connection sucessfull. After login is done I can connect cable again and have internet connection and ssh connection together without problems as long as I don't logout ssh. Next login same procedure. Annoying and unnecessary wear I think.

I tried too google it an found that I had to add some IP table routing rules for the kernel to use proper interface for ssh. But I understood it barely.

Here's my routing table:

```
route -v
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s25
default         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s25
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s25
192.168.43.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

When I triy to "bind" gateway adress when attempt ssh connection I get this:

```
ssh -b 192.168.43.1 pi@raspberrypi
bind: 192.168.43.1: Cannot assign requested address
ssh: connect to host raspberrypi port 22: Cannot assign requested address
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and where? Thank's a lot!

Comment: You have two default routes.  You have to delete one to use the other.  Since you're doing this all by hand, it's going to need you to configure routing properly.  How are you setting up the 'Wifi connection'?  Manually through `/etc/network/interfaces` or with `nm-cli` or something else?

Comment: For setting up wifi connection it's all automatic... The only thing I do is enable wireless connection in system tray.

I don't do that manually. Should I? I also use wireless for internet in some case but not when trying ssh.

Comment: I'm confused now by your network setup, and lack of information.  Which system is having issues with Internet?  The Pi Zero, or some other system?  The system that's having this issue, is this a GUI or a CLI based environment?

Comment: Ok...

Theres my laptop with ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GUI I think) who has 2 network interface to handle with.

ethernet for internet, wlan for ssh to raspberry. routing table shown above is for ubuntu system on my laptop.

Comment: Are you now hacking my system thanks to my routing table? You're profile photo freaks me out haha :D

Comment: So let me get this straight, when you're connected to Ethernet only, it works without issue.  But when you're connected to Ethernet *and* the Wifi, the Internet connectivity breaks.  Correct?

Comment: Nope.  No it's more like de wifi connection breaks when both are connected. The ethernet interface is for internet and it always work, the wlan is connected to smartphone access point for ssh into raspberry pi, no internet connection at all there. When I try to ssh over wlan to my raspberry it's there's no host. That's why I have to disconnect ethernet cable, connect to raspberry over wlan and then reconnect ethernet cable for internet connection. After this procedure everything works fine. My aim is to tell the kernel to use wlan interface for ssh and not ethernet (as default I think).